# Passing the parameter of an Object into an Object method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This a simplified version of what I am trying to solve:
In Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.0, Activerecord

Segment `has_many` Sales

```
Sale.find(1).bid = 1
Sale.find(1).ask = 2
Sale.find(2).bid = 10
Sale.find(2).ask = 20
etc
```

When I write this method:

```
class Segment
  def add_stuff(param)
    sales.map{ |s| s.param }.inject(:+)
  end
end
```

Question: How to pass in `bid` or `ask` as `param` and interpolate that param properly within the block?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use `map` on active record association, when you can use `pluck` or other querying method like, for example `sum`:

```
def add_staff(param)
  sales.sum(param)
end
```

Just for the completeness, here is how to do it with `map` - note however that map is much slower and error prone than querying methods:

```
def add_staff(param)
  sales.map {|s| s[param]}        # if param is name of the column on sales model.
end
```

Or more general, where param is name of association or custom (non-column) method

```
def add_staff(param)
  sales.map(&param)   # Or map {|s| s.send(param) }
end
```

Comment: BroiSatse, thanks...this is the 2nd time you've answered a question of mine and I'm very appreciative.  I did a quick google of pluck and sum and you just opened a whole new world for me.  I'm at that point in my development where I need to start thinking hard about SQL queries rather than just making do.